# Insertion psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I try to insert data in exist table:

```
img_query = "INSERT INTO images (img_name) VALUES ({}) RETURNING id".format(img)
img_id = self.engine.execute(img_query)
```

I use sqlalchemy engine for execution.
As a result received this type of mistakes:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "_Group_Large_Group_12_Group_Large_Group_12_15"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO images (img_name) VALUES (12_Group_Large_Group_1...
```

I tried to change "12_" on "*12*" or replace all "_" on "-". Result not changed I received same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow psycopg2 to do the quoting for you:

```
img_query = "INSERT INTO images (img_name) VALUES (%s) RETURNING id;"
img_id = self.engine.execute(img_query,(img,))
```